# comparing the first column of two files and printing the entire row of the second file if the first columns match

Tags: awk, grep, join

I have two files in these formats:

file1 :

```
air
smell
hand
dude
road
cat
```

file 2:

```
air,4,21,01,13,3,2
smell,21,4,2,5,6
dude,1,31,42,1
road,1,4,2,1,4
cat,1,5,6,3,1
hand,1,4,2,1,6
mouse,1,3,5,6,2
```

what I want to do is print the entire row of file 2, if the first string in column 1 of file 2 is found in file 1, and I want to keep the order of file 1.

expected output:

```
air,4,21,01,13,3,2
smell,21,4,2,5,6
hand,1,4,2,1,6
dude,1,31,42,1
road,1,4,2,1,4
cat,1,5,6,3,1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR {a[$1]; next}; $1 in a' file1 file2
```

edit:

Interpreted the wrong file for the ordering. A new attempt (requires `gawk` if that is acceptable)

```
gawk -F, '
    FNR==NR {a[NR]=$1; next}; 
    {b[$1]=$0}
    END{for (i in a) if (a[i] in b) print b[a[i]]}
' file1 file2
```

edit 2:

With nowmal `awk`, and swapping the files around:

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR {a[$1]=$0; next}; $1 in a {print a[$1]}' file2 file1
```

Answer (score 3):

```
join -t, -1 2 -2 1 <(nl -s, -ba -nrz file1 | sort -t, -k2) \
<(sort -t, -k1 file2) | sort -t, -k2 | cut -d, -f1,3-
```

The lines in `file1` are numbered and the result is `sort`ed on 2nd field. This is then `join`ed with `file2` (`sort`ed on 1st field):

```
air,000001,4,21,01,13,3,2
cat,000006,1,5,6,3,1
dude,000004,1,31,42,1
hand,000003,1,4,2,1,6
road,000005,1,4,2,1,4
smell,000002,21,4,2,5,6
```

the result is then `sort`ed on 2nd field (i.e. the line numbers) to restore the original line order and then the same 2nd field is removed with `cut`:

```
air,4,21,01,13,3,2
smell,21,4,2,5,6
hand,1,4,2,1,6
dude,1,31,42,1
road,1,4,2,1,4
cat,1,5,6,3,1
```

Comment: i get a return message `Missing name for redirect` for some reason. I'm pretty sure I'm using your code as is. Maybe it's my system specifics?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 & tc shell

Answer (score 0):

You can use the simple grep command.

```
grep -f file1 file2
```

Comment: This is close, but does not meet the requirement of preserving the output in the order of file1.

Comment: My bad, I over looked the _**"I want to keep the order of file 1"**_ part in the question.