# Compare first and second column of two files and print the row from second file if there is a match

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk

I went through the answers in the following question but I couldn't get expected output as shown below.

[comparing the first column of two files and printing the entire row of the second file if the first columns match](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/216511/comparing-the-first-column-of-two-files-and-printing-the-entire-row-of-the-secon)

File 1

```
CLASS|124655
CLASS|124656
CLASS|124657
CLASS|124658
```

File 2

```
CLASS|124655|STEVE|SMITH||
CLASS|124656|ROGERS|KNIGHT||
CLASS|124657|MITCHELL|BRADFORD||
CLASS|124657||||1236536
CLASS|124658|NORMAN|JONES||
CLASS|124658||||1236539
CLASS|124665|JEFF|JONES||
CLASS|124665||||1236556
```

Expected output

```
CLASS|124655|STEVE|SMITH||
CLASS|124656|ROGERS|KNIGHT||
CLASS|124657|MITCHELL|BRADFORD||
CLASS|124657||||1236536
CLASS|124658|NORMAN|JONES||
CLASS|124658||||1236539
```

I tried grep -f file1 file2 but it got killed by the Kernel and it was taking too long to process. File 1 and File 2 have more than 1m records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `awk`solution would be this:

```
$ awk -v FS="|" 'NR==FNR {get[$1"|"$2]++; next} get[$1"|"$2]' f1.txt f2.txt
```

Don't know if this works for 1m records.